# Can Lorentz transformation be applied between two free falling observers?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Assuming there are two observer A and B at different positions near a black hole, A and B are free falling towards to the black hole, so they are both inertial frame of references. Can we apply Lorentz transformation between these two coordinate frames?